# How to Drop Table using Textbox in Microsoft access using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

sorry to bother again. but i really need your help.. 
The Problem is:
I create a table in Ms Access using textbox with button in vb.net (visual studio 2010)

But now...

I want to delete or drop the table using textbox with button..

How can I drop the table i created???

here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub


'Create Table
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=masterlist.accdb"
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = " CREATE TABLE " & txtID.Text & " (ID COUNTER, [Name] INTEGER) "
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Console.WriteLine("Table created.")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub


'Delete table?
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=database\masterlist.accdb"
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = " DROP TABLE " & txtID.Text
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                Console.WriteLine("Table drop.")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: You haven't mentioned a problem, only what you're trying to do. You may want to describe any exceptions you're getting or what particularly isn't working

Comment: Sorry.. How can I drop the table i created???

Comment: Well your code looks fine at first glance, that's why I'm wondering if you're getting a specific exception somewhere, or what currently happens when you run it?

Comment: OMG - Sorry.. My Code is working fine.. The only problem is I didn't Close the MS Access.. I think I need some sleep now.. Anyway. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Try replace using con to: Dim con 
Or 
Add another n to con 
con = conn you forgot an n